# "Invaild universal character" for iOS?

Tags: ios, unicode, character-encoding

When writing a iOS string literal, encountered a strange question. It's Invaild universal character.The following code:

```
NSString *str = @"\ud83d\udc4d"; // Prompt error: Invaild universal character
```

But, the following code is ok:

```
NSString *str = @"\u2614\ufe0f";
```

Why?

In addition, I found that as long as it is \ ud8xx, \ ud9xx, \ udexx, \ udfxx format error.

What reason is this?

Comment: Study the definition of UTF8.  The `\u` character literals are interpreted as ASCII/UTF8 characters, not UTF16/32.  Any UTF8 character beginning with a `\udXXX` is a special code in UTF8.

Comment: @HotLicks `\u` denotes a Unicode scalar value and has nothing to do with UTF-8/16/32.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  `\xNN` would be a standard ASCII/UNICODE hex literal.  I'm a little rusty on those escapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode escape sequences can't be used to encode surrogate code points individually (those between `0xD800` and `0xDFFF`), you have to specify the actual supplementary code point:

```
NSString *str = @"\U0001F44D";
```

Comment: , Thank you for your answer, "\ u2614 \ ufe0f" this OK, because it does not belong to the encode surrogate for.